# Properties of the modulo operation

Tags: c++, c, math, properties, modulo

I have the compute the sum S = (a*x + b*y + c) % N. Yes it looks like a quadratic equation but it is not because the x and y have some properties and have to be calculated using some recurrence relations. Because the sum exceeds even the limits of unsigned long long I want to know how could I compute that sum using the properties of the modulo operation, properties that allow the writing of the sum something like that(I say something because I do not remember exactly how are those properties): (a*x)%N + (b*y)%N + c%N, thus avoiding exceeding the limits of unsigned long long.

Thanks in advance for your concern! :)

Comment: **not** completely off topic, since the problem is constrained by the word size limits of common languages

Comment: Have you just tried breaking it up into that form with a test set of data to see if it even works (without delving into determining whether it can be done that way), sometimes the easiest thing is to just try it, you learn a lot that way

Comment: Have you considered "S = (a*x % N) + (b*y % N) + (c % N)"? More specifically, are any of these negative?

Comment: @Alnitak: I agree. But sorry, can't cancel close vote...

Comment: Hmm, if the sum would exceed the bounds it is very likely that just one term would exceed the bounds. The sum at most needs only 2 bits more space than each term.

Comment: other solution is to use a bigint implementation so you don't have this problem anymore :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`a % N = x` means that for some integers `0 <= x < N` and `m`: `m * N + x = a`.

You can simply deduce then that if `a % N = x` and `b % N = y` then

```
(a + b) % N =
= (m * N + x + l * N + y) % N =
= ((m + l) * N + x + y) % N =
= (x + y) % N =
= (a % N + b % N) % N.
```

We know that  `0 < x + y < 2N`, that is why you need to keep remainder calculation. This shows that it is okay to split the summation and calculate the remainders separately and then add them, but don't forget to get the remainder for the sum.

For multiplication:

```
(a * b) % N =
= ((m * N + x) * (l * N + y)) % N =
= ((m * l + x * l + m * y) * N + x * y) % N =
= (x * y) % N =
= ((a % N) * (b % N)) % N.
```

Thus you can also do the same with products.

These properties can be simply derived in a more general setting using some abstract algebra (the remainders form a factor ring `Z/nZ`).

Comment: But you can even pull the modulo into the product.

Comment: Excellent.  I suspected but didn't remember off-hand that the modulo could be brought into the products as well.

Answer (score 8):

You can take the idea even further, if needed:

```
S = ( (a%N)*(x%N)+(b%N)*(y%N)+c%N )%N
```

Answer (score 6):

You can apply the modulus to each term of the sum as you've suggested; but even so after summing them you must apply the modulus again to get your final result.

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
   int x = (7 + 7 + 7) % 10;

   int y = (7 % 10 + 7 % 10 + 7 % 10) % 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You remember right. The equation you gave, where you %N every of the summands is correct. And that would be exactly what I use. You should also %N for every partial sum (and the total) again, as the addition results can be still greater than N. BUT be careful this works only if your size limit is at least twice as big as your N. If this is not the case, it can get really nasty.

Btw for the following %N operations of the partial sums, you dont have to perform a complete division, a check > N and if bigger just subtraction of N is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Not only can you reduce all variable mod n before starting the calculation, you can write your own mod-mul to compute a*x mod n by using a shift-and-add method and reduce the result mod n at each step. That way your intermediate calculations will only require one more bit than n. Once these products are computed, you can add them pairwise and reduce mod n after each addition which will also not require more than 1 bit beyond the range of n.

There is a python implementation of modular multiplication in my answer to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773628/better-ways-to-implement-a-modulo-operation-algorithm-question/2774319#2774319) Conversion to C should be trivial.