# Mod of two large numbers in C++

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I have a class named `LargeNum`, which stores large numbers by array such as `digit[]`. Because `int` is not large enough to store it.

The base is `10000`, so number `'9876 8764 7263'` is stored like：

```
digit[4] = {9876, 8764, 7263};
```

(the base can be changed into `10` or `100`, like `digit[12] = {9,8,7,6,8,7,6,4,7,2,6,3}`)

The problem is that I want to overload operator `%`, so than I　can get the remainder of two large numbers. Overloading operator `*`, `-` between large numbers is finished by dealing with every digit of the large number. But I really don't how to do so with `%`. Like:

```
{1234,7890,1234} % {4567,0023}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2773953/213550 Related

Comment: The result of this operation can (and should) be `LargeNum` by itself. You'd better off implementing all the other arithmetic operators (`+,-,*,/`), and then you can implement the modulo operator pretty easily. You might find [this example](https://github.com/barakman/Num) useful.

Comment: Use long division. Implementing division will be unpleasant no matter how you do it. :(

Comment: in this case the long division is limited, because, A % B, both are large numbers. So the array is used to store them by digits.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77466528/6328256 for how to utilize [`boost/multiprecision/cpp_int`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp) to do this with only a couple of lines. (As per StackOverflow Policy, I can't answer the same question twice; however, this question might be higher in search results).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pseudocode should be:

```
while digits_source > digits_base {
    while first_digit_source > first_digit_base {
        source -= base << (digits_source - digits_base)
    }

    second_digit_source += first_digit_source * LargeNum.base
    first_digit_source = 0
    digits_source--
}

while (source >= base) {
    source -= base
}

return source
```

This should take advantage of your "digits" of the large number.

Edit: For simplicity, I am assuming that a single digit of you array can contain (numerically speaking) two digits. If it cannot, then the code would become quite tricky because you cannot do `second_digit_source += first_digit_source * LargeNum.base`

---

Edit:

Regarding an example operation (base = 10000)

```
{65,0000,0099} % {32,0001}
```

As `65` is > `32`, then proceed to do:

```
65 - 32 = 33
0 - 1 = -1
```

Then we have `{33, -1, 99} % {32, 1}`. Proceed again

```
33 - 32 = 1
-1 - 1 = -2
```

We have `{1, -2, 99} % {32, 1}`. Because 32 > 1, the we join the two first digits of the source and we have `{1*1000 - 2, 99} % {32, 1}`. Now we can go into the simple `while`, simply by doing the minus operation. The while does a full comparison of `source >= base` because we cannot afford to have negative digits. However, during the first part of the algorithm we can because we are guaranteeing that the combination of the two first digits will be positive.

Comment: Thank your for your answer.  For example, if I want to do 97283847283 % 2389238494; what do these exactly mean : digits_source  , source , and so on in your pseudo code.

Comment: In your first example of LongInt, `'9876 8764 7263'`, digits_source is 3, source is `{9876, 8764, 7263}`, first_digit_source is 9876. You should stick to one simple example, and it would be easier for the responses, instead of hoping with different data examples, let me edit the answer for the full process.

Comment: Wow, it's pretty cool ! By the way, if {2,-5}%{2,7}  in base of 10,  then {2,-5} is smaller, the result is 2*10-5. I've tested several simple number and it worked out! I will try it in program later. It's very nice of you to show such clear explanation, and this way of thinking is very excellent!

Comment: There are some corner cases in which there is a number like `{12, 23, -2}` or `{1, -1, 100, -2}`. Those can be addressed by decreasing one on the digit (respectively: `{12, 22, 998}` and `{0, 999, 99, 998}`). My algorithm may yield those numbers and maybe they should be sanitized. You should evaluate this (maybe a "sanitize" process before returning the value)