# mod of two big hex numbers in c++

Tags: c++, math, encryption, numbers, hex

i have two large  hex numbers each one at least 70 digits (in decimal) and i am trying to calculate the value hex_a%hex_b:

```cpp
string hex_a="1133A5DCDEF3216A63EB879A82F5A1DC4490CCF6412492CF1B242DB";
string hex_b="AAB3A5DCDEF3216A6AAA2F5A1DC4490CCF6412492CF1B242DB";
```

i try to convert the two hex numbers to decimal with stoi and store the value in string:

```cpp
string a=to_string(stoi(hex_a, 0, 16));
```

but i am getting an error when using stoi method:

```cpp
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  stoi
Aborted (core dumped)
```

how can i calculate mod of two big numbers in c++ ?

Comment: Do you remember how you learned long division in elementary school? How it works? Simply implement the long division algorithm using hexadecimal. That's how to do it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes but i am facing a problem in storing large decimal in c++. which type can store a decimal number of 80 digits in c++ ?

Comment: The trick is you don't you store them as a string (as you are already do) and calculate digit by digit using carry. As @SamVarshavchik said it is like elementry school, did you divide large numbers in one go? Or digit by digit? There strictly isn't a need to convert to decimal first (though big int libraries are available)

Comment: in c++ we can calculate mod of two decimal numbers by using the operator %. i try to convert each one of the two hexes to decimal but i did not success.

Comment: _"i try to convert each one of the two hexes to decimal but i did not succes"_ - If you show that attempt, perhaps someone can point out what you are doing wrong

Comment: @AD *"which type can store a decimal number of 80 digits in c++ ?"* -- You've made the question harder by converting to decimal. Count the hexadecimal digits and multiply by 4. That's how many bits you need. If you need at most 64 bits, then the value fits in `unisgned long long` regardless of your implementation.

Comment: @AD *"we can calculate mod of two decimal numbers by using the operator %."* -- Not exactly. Integers are not stored in decimal by the computer. The operator `%` gives the modulus of two numbers stored in an integer type. If you must mention a base for the number, "binary" is more appropriate than "decimal".

Comment: Either use a big-number library, or do the computation yourself as done at school...

Comment: @JaMiT if this question is closed as a duplicate by someone can you tag me so I can post my answer to that question? (it does not have a `boost/multiprecision/cpp_int` snippet which is arguably better than the manual answer to that question). 

For the benefit of future search engine users.

Comment: as @SamVarshavchik mentioned you need to do a long division. The base of operations is up to your choice: `16`, `256`, `(1<<16)`, `(1<<32)`, `(1<<64)`, `(16<<n)`. You need to choose your digital base and read one digit at a time. I would break the numbers into 4 digits of base `(1<<64)`. But you can choose 35 digits of base 256.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize [`boost/multiprecision/cpp_int`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp):

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using boost::multiprecision::cpp_int;

int main() {
  std::string hex_a = "0x1133A5DCDEF3216A63EB879A82F5A1DC4490CCF6412492CF1B242DB";
  std::string hex_b = "0xAAB3A5DCDEF3216A6AAA2F5A1DC4490CCF6412492CF1B242DB";
  cpp_int a(hex_a), b(hex_b);
  cpp_int result = a % b;
  std::cout << "Result as int: " << result << '\n';
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << std::hex << result;
  std::string result_hex = ss.str();
  std::cout << "Result as hex: 0x" << result_hex << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Or [GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library (GMP)](https://gmplib.org/), which might be faster:

```
#include <gmp.h>

int main() {
  mpz_t a, b, result;
  mpz_init(a);
  mpz_init(b);
  mpz_init(result);
  mpz_set_str(a, "1133A5DCDEF3216A63EB879A82F5A1DC4490CCF6412492CF1B242DB", 16);
  mpz_set_str(b, "AAB3A5DCDEF3216A6AAA2F5A1DC4490CCF6412492CF1B242DB", 16);
  mpz_mod(result, a, b);
  gmp_printf("Result as int: %Zd\n", result);
  gmp_printf("Result as hex: Ox%Zx\n", result);
  mpz_clear(a);
  mpz_clear(b);
  mpz_clear(result);
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Result as int: 887778964514700662847592530576646032246936850244260028835776
Result as hex: 0x8d6e6cdeb792c9d42b257481c738989f678484c94fd6b567c0
```

Confirmation of the same result in Python:

```py
>>> hex_a = "0x1133A5DCDEF3216A63EB879A82F5A1DC4490CCF6412492CF1B242DB"
>>> hex_b = "0xAAB3A5DCDEF3216A6AAA2F5A1DC4490CCF6412492CF1B242DB"
>>> a = int(hex_a, 16)
>>> b = int(hex_b, 16)
>>> result = a % b
>>> print(f'Result as int: {result}')
Result as int: 887778964514700662847592530576646032246936850244260028835776
>>> print(f'Result as hex: 0x{result:x}')
Result as hex: 0x8d6e6cdeb792c9d42b257481c738989f678484c94fd6b567c0
```

Comment: thank you so much brother. appreciate it !!

Comment: Though you're still missing the step back to a hex string. And if the input and output need to be hex, it's worth checking if this is faster than just computing the modulo using the rules of modulo math in hex land.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans PTAL updated :)

Comment: hi my code became slower by 50 percent after making 4 time calculations (a%b). is these because the boost library is slow ? or because these consider a very big calculation in comparison to others ?

Comment: @SashSinha  could you please recommend to me a faster library than boost/multiprecision/cpp_int  ?

Comment: I added an example using the [GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library (GMP)](https://gmplib.org/), can you try that?

Comment: @SashSinha i am getting an error when i trying to compile the file please see the edited question above.

Comment: okay i fixed i add -lgmp. i will check the speed and tell you if it improved thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't convert such a big number to "int", "long", "long long", "double", etc.

The first approach is to implement basic math operations (+,-,multiply 16 or shift) on strings and than implement division algorithm yourself.
See for reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm

The second approach is to use and "arbitrary-precision arithmetic library":
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software

For example https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html